# My asp.net dropdown list is wrapping records

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a asp.net web application and the dropdown list works fine and is sorted correctly initially but after a large amount of records, the dropdown wraps the records around to the beginning. For example: If I have 100 records, the dropdown acts as it should and the records are displayed as follows:

```
1   - record 1
2   - record 2
3   - record 3
.
.
.
100 - record 100
```

But if I have a large amount of records, say like 100000 records, it looks like this:

```
35001  - record 35001
35002  - record 35002
.
.
.
100000 - record 100000
1      - record 1
2      - record 2
3      - record 3
.
.
.
35000  - record 35000
```

Anyone have an idea what is causing this behavior and how to resolve it? Thanks.

Comment: A dropdown with ~100000 items is way to many; what user would want to scroll through that?

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't show the code :-(

Comment: Yeah my first thought were that they have way too much data in the dropdown but you'd be surprised the kind of application designs we have at work. When it was designed they probably didn't anticipate that much data but now its thousands of records in the dropdown smh. I'm suggesting they change that somehow but in the meantime I still have to resolve the current issue..

Answer (score 2):

The WebControls.DropDownList doesn't have a Sort/Order property/method.
Instead, it shows exactly in the order that the items were inserted.

Your behaviour should be easily verified, if it is not, it is probably an error on the ServerSide/CodeBehind.

If you are Binding it using DataSource/DataBind, add each item individually (ddl.Items.Add) to see if the results are the same.

You said that the ordering is all over but we cannot see the actual data/order so, are you sure is not just ordering as string, and you want ordered as numbers?

Ex.: 
`string[] s = new[]{"2","11"}; 
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", s.OrderBy(x=> x))); //result "11","2"`

Anyway, a DropDown with 100000 is a BAD idea, the page will become too slow, you can test it on a simple page.

Comment: I believe the code has a stored procedure that gets the needed data from the database and then uses DataBind to bind the data to the dropdown list. I totally agree that a dropdown with 100000+ records is a very bad idea but the system users are used to that and are not complaining so I'm not sure they're gonna change that just yet. They are just mad that sort is messed up and it takes them longer to do their job.

Comment: The ordering is done within the stored procedure and inserted into a table that is used to populate the dropdown. So the data get sorted and then inserted into the table with an autoincrementing ID so I know it it's sorted correctly in the dropdown cos the dropdown also displays the same ID for each record.

Comment: I think you made a mistake there "I know it it's sorted correctly in the dropdown" Isn't this exactly the problem? Maybe it is that you know that is correct in the table, in which case I would ask you if it is a DB table (does your select have an order by clause? if not there is no guarantee what the order will be), if it is a System.Data.DataTable then you should observe the BindingCode and check if anyone is messing with the order (in table.DefaultView.Sort)

Comment: The other possibility is the front end is trying to sort it - maybe some javascript code?

Comment: Hmm... I'll have to look a bit closer. I didn't write the code and not too familiar with .Net cos I'm a Java Developer. The code was written back in 2007 so I'm just trying to understand what's going on. Thanks for the help btw. I'll let you know if I find anything.